# Bitizen Store Restock

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

So I just discovered the bitizen store and was excited to see you can unlock scenes more easily this way. I used the Chadra Fan to unlock the Holonet Cineplex and then tried to use Mon Calamari to unlock the Mon Cala Aquarium. I "missed" because my elevator is too fast and now he's gone from the store. Is there any way to get him back? Will the store restock ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a bitizen has been unlocked or bought, they will start randomly appearing in arrivals to board the elevator. Just keep playing and delivering people to their floors and you'll eventually see them again.

Comment: So the store will never stock the Mon Calamari again for 1 bux? Because I unlocked the Mon Calamari species weeks ago and have NEVER seen one randomly.

Comment: @Robert That is correct.

Comment: That sucks, I hope you are right and that he will eventually show up randomly, but I really doubt it. I think it's bugged like everything else about this game.

Comment: @Robert, same issue here.  I unlocked the Mon Calamari during the Christmas event - and got a decoration droid or something instead of the M.C. Yet to see one!